# Incorrect used/free space

Tags: debian, filesystems

I've encountered this issue. I have a VM with Debian 8 on it. I gave that disk 350gb, /dev/sda1 is 344gb, used is 330gb and it's 100%. Situation is as follows, I'm importing huge mysql dump (300gb in single file) and it's still running (i.e. it wasn't interrupted due to reaching the limit). When it hit 0, I moved some tables and and index files of some tables to the host (~170gb) but system didn't reflect that and still says that it's 100% used. Question is, what can I do about it without anyhow interrupting that import so that it can finish up when there's more space?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, what you're trying to do is not possible as you're moving files that are still open by another process, so they will continue to get updated properly, avoiding space that is already used by them.

The free space reported is actually right, even if you don't see the files in the directory listing anymore.  As long as the file is open by a process, its allocated space will keep its integrity.

There's no way to ensure that a 300GB dump will fit on your partition, but perhaps removing the indexes might help a bit.